# separate "in" from "in which"

Tags: grammar

The original sentence I saw is "Teenagers often have episodes of anger and negativity ***in which*** they slam doors and scream at family members".

My questions would be, can we reorder the position of the "***in***"? Like this, "Teenagers often have episodes of anger and negativity ***which*** they slam doors ***in*** and scream at family members". And, will it sound unnatural?

Comment: Maybe use _**during** which_ in this case instead of _**in** which_. Anyway, to address your question: be careful reordering like that. It would be best to keep the _in which_ together. When I first looked at the second sentence, I thought the _in_ applied to the doors themselves, as opposed to the episode, but that could just be me.

Comment: You could, but the result is awkward and not natural. There's no reason to reorder the position of "in which", so stick with the original.

Comment: @BillJ: Consider a simpler but structurally identical context: *That's my caravan, which I work **in** and sleep.* It's fine to put the ***single*** preposition before ***which*** or after ***sleep***, OR to include it before ***both*** verbs, but I don't think it's syntactically valid to only include it after the ***first*** verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

episode means a period of time.
you have two sentences here.

> Teenagers often have episodes of anger and negativity.
>   They slam doors and scream at family members in that period of time.

you can combine them like:
Teenagers often have episodes of anger and negativity (when = in which = that) they slam doors and scream at family members.

it is noteworthy noting that in this adverbial, one **cannot move and delete** the prepositions of "in" and "on", etc. If you want to eliminate them, you have to discard the whole of that adverbial, i.e. "in which". but for the adverbial of "where", the story is different.

these are examples for "where"

> The building **where** he works is new.
>   The building **in which** he works is new.
>   The building **which** he works **in** is new.
>   The building **that** he works **in** is new.
>   The building he works **in** is new.

these are examples for "when"

> I will never forget the day **when** I graduated.
>   I will never forget the day **on which** I graduated.
>   I will never forget the day **that** I graduated.
>   I will never forget the day I graduated.

Comment: Do you mean we can discard "when", "in which", and "that" but we can't discard "where"?

Comment: I added some example, please attention to the position of the prepositions